# Replace Quartz Spring configuration xml and properties with @Configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, quartz-scheduler

I'm migrating a web application built with Spring 3 to a Spring 4 Boot based app.

I'd like to replace all xml and properties with a @Configuration class.

Original spring xml config

```
<bean id="scheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:quartz.properties"/>
    <property name="applicationContextSchedulerContextKey">
        <value>applicationContext</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Original quartz.properties

```
org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource=psqldatasource
org.quartz.dataSource.psqldatasource.driver=${db.driver}
org.quartz.dataSource.psqldatasource.URL=${db.url}
org.quartz.dataSource.psqldatasource.user=${db.usr}
org.quartz.dataSource.psqldatasource.password=${db.pwd}
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 3

org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties = false
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
```

I've managed to replace spring xml with the following code, but it still use an external quartz.properties to configure most of the quartz features, including datasource.

```
@Bean
public Scheduler configureScheduler() throws SchedulerException {
    StdSchedulerFactory f = new StdSchedulerFactory();
    f.initialize(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("quartz.properties"));
    return f.getScheduler();
}
```

Note that this leads to the following output during app boot :

```
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 3 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX' - which supports persistence. and is not clustered.
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to achieve a full Java Spring configuration using the following code :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("com.myapp")
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Bean
    public SchedulerFactoryBean configureScheduler() {
        SchedulerFactoryBean f = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
        f.setDataSource(dataSource);
        f.setJobFactory(new SpringBeanJobFactory());
        f.setAutoStartup(false);
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount", "3");
        properties.setProperty("org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties", "false");
        properties.setProperty("org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass", "org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate");
        f.setQuartzProperties(properties);
        f.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        f.setApplicationContextSchedulerContextKey("applicationContext");
        return f;
    }
}
```

This produce the following output during app boot

```
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore' - which supports persistence. and is not clustered.
```

To my purpose this is satisfying ; although i'm not sure with the different job-store implementation (was JobStoreTX and now LocalDataSourceJobStore). I'm wondering this is related to the use of the spring autowired datasource.